# Malloc and free

Tags: performance, c, memory-management

I'm looking for help speeding up some code I'm tinkering with.

The rest of the code, as well as my 'benchmark', can be found [here](https://github.com/Levalicious/lalloc/tree/0f9ee7d1175d13a7fa75ea6669284bfaaad0848b).

```c
 
#ifndef LALLOC_H
#define LALLOC_H

#define PAGESIZE (1048576)

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct bblk bblock;
typedef bblock* bb;
struct bblk {
    size_t ind;
    bb next;
    size_t occ;
    char mem[PAGESIZE - (sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(bb) + sizeof(size_t))];
} __attribute__((packed));

typedef struct smmblk memblock;
typedef memblock* mb;
struct smmblk {
    mb prev;
    mb next;
    void* end;
    bb bblk;
    bool free;
} __attribute__((packed));

size_t bbhdr = (sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(bb) + sizeof(size_t));

bb first;

/**
 * @author Lev Knoblock
 * @notice Allocates a 'big block' of memory using mmap and inserts 1 'small block' into it
 * @dev Consider moving away from 1 page of memory. Maybe larger blocks would be better.
 * @param
 * @return bblk *
 */
bb bbinit() {
    bb out = mmap(NULL, PAGESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_POPULATE, -1, 0);
    if (out == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("%s", sys_errlist[errno]);
        exit(40);
    }

    /* Big blocks are appended to an append-only linked list.
     * Since initially all memory in the block is free, the
     * occupancy is set to 0 */
    out->next = NULL;
    out->occ = 0;

    mb t = (mb) out->mem;
    /* The internal small block has no predecessors or
     * successors, but spans the full block width */
    t->prev = NULL;
    t->next = NULL;
    t->end = out->mem + (PAGESIZE - (sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(bb) + sizeof(size_t)));
    t->free = true;
    t->bblk = out;
    return out;
}

/**
 * @author Lev Knoblock
 * @notice Allocates a slice of memory by creating an appropriately sized small block in a big block
 * @dev Well its somehow slower than the prototype and I swear I knew what was making that one slow
 * @param 'big block' to allocate from, size of slice
 * @return void* to memory, or NULL if no space was found.
 */
static void* bblkalloc(bb blk, size_t size) {
    mb sb = (mb) blk->mem;
    /* Find the first free small block */
    while (1) {
        if (sb->free) break;
        tryGetNext:;
        if (sb->next == NULL) {
            /* Reached end of big block */
            return NULL;
        }
        sb = sb->next;
    }

    /* Remaining space in small block */
    size_t frsize = sb->end - (((void*)sb) + sizeof(memblock));

    /* If there isn't enough space to fit a new small block
     * find another block that will fit one */
    if (frsize < (size + sizeof(memblock))) {
        goto tryGetNext;
    }

    /* Initialize the new small block by stealing
     * space from the end of the 'current' small block */
    mb nsb = sb->end - (sizeof(memblock) + size);
    nsb->prev = sb;
    nsb->next = sb->next;
    nsb->end = sb->end;
    nsb->free = false;
    nsb->bblk = blk;

    /* Append new small block to list */
    sb->end = nsb;
    if (sb->next != NULL) sb->next->prev = nsb;
    sb->next = nsb;

    sb->bblk = blk;
    blk->occ++;
    /* Return pointer past allocation header */
    return ((void*)nsb) + sizeof(memblock);
}

/**
 * @author Lev Knoblock
 * @notice Allocates a slice of memory from the memory pool
 * @dev Currently has no functionality for reducing number of big blocks.
 * @param size of slice
 * @return void*
 */
void* lalloc(size_t size) {
    void* out;
    bb curr = first;
    unsigned int ind = 0;
    do {
        if (curr == NULL) {
            /* If current big block is null, set it up with its first small block */
            curr = bbinit();
            curr->ind = ind;
            if (ind == 0) first = curr;
        }
        /*
        if (curr->occ) {
            curr = curr->next;
            ind++;
            continue;
        }
         */
        out = bblkalloc(curr, size);
        /* If allocation fails go to the next big block (and allocate it if necessary)
         * otherwise, return the valid pointer */
        if (out != NULL) return out;
        //curr->occ = 1;
        curr = curr->next;
        ind++;
    } while (1);
}

/**
 * @author Lev Knoblock
 * @notice Frees a slice of memory from the memory pool
 * @dev Not really sure how to optimize further.
 * @param void* to slice
 * @return
 */
void lfree(void* a) {
    /* Decrement pointer to get to begining of header */
    mb sb = a - sizeof(memblock);
    sb->free = true;

    if (sb->prev != NULL && sb->prev->free) {
        /* If previous block exists and is free, extend it
         * to wrap over this one and remove pointers to
         * this block header */
        sb->prev->end = sb->end;
        sb->prev->next = sb->next;
        if (sb->next != NULL) sb->next->prev = sb->prev;

        /* Replace block pointer on stack */
        sb = sb->prev;
    }

    if (sb->next != NULL && sb->next->free) {
        /* If next block exists extend current one over
         * it and scrub pointers to it */
        sb->end = sb->next->end;
        sb->next = sb->next->next;
        if (sb->next != NULL) sb->next->prev = sb;
    }

    /* Decrement occupancy */
    sb->bblk->occ--;
}

#endif
```

Comment: (If I should put an explanation for how it is supposed to work, let me know, I wasn't sure)

Comment: (Also I realize there was a goto in there, I'm sorry, I kind of like goto?)

Comment: You don't need to apologise for the `goto`, nor does it bring your question off-topic... but you'll definitely be called out on it during the review.

Comment: When adding additional information you should [edit] your question  instead of adding a comment. Learn more about comments including when to comment and when not to in [the Help Center page about Comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please clarify the purpose of the code. What made you write this? What was wrong with the tools already available?

Comment: @Mast Mainly, as a learning experience. I wanted to learn about memory allocation, and I thought this would be a fun thing to try instead of copying a design from wikipedia. Most of my code has really no purpose beyond experimenting with something.

Answer (score 5):

### Variable linkage

```
bb first;
```

looks like it's in a header file. That means every time you include it from a different module, it will be re-declared with its own separate address. That's unlikely to be what you want. Instead, declare it `extern`, and then define it once in a C file.

Beyond that, though: why declare it in the header at all? It's an implementation detail that you shouldn't expose to your users.

Further, it looks like absolutely everything - including your function bodies - is in the header. Maybe your theory is that inlining everything produces faster code than having a more standard .c/.h layout. If this library is to be included in another project as a .so/.dll there is some non-zero chance that that's the case, but if this library is included in-source with any kind of self-respecting compiler that has whole program optimization, that chance drops to zero. Basically, I would consider this premature optimization and would be surprised if it's worth doing this over having a separated .c that better isolates your design and reduces code re-declaration.

### Nested includes

These:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

need to be trimmed down to only what's strictly necessary to declare the symbols in your `lalloc.h`. `errno` can definitely be removed; `stdbool` cannot; and I'm unsure about the others. The trimmed includes would be moved to the .c.

### stderr

```
    printf("%s", sys_errlist[errno]);
```

should likely be `fprintf`ed to `stderr` instead. Also, `fprintf` is not necessary; you can use `puts`/`fputs`.

### Mystery error codes

```
    exit(40);
```

should get a `#define`.

### Yes, goto is actually bad

This:

```
while (1) {
    tryGetNext:;
    // ...
}

if (frsize < (size + sizeof(memblock))) {
    goto tryGetNext;
}
```

just demonstrates that your `while` has not adequately captured what you're *actually* looping over. An outer loop should include everything everything up to this `goto`; the existing `while` should become an inner loop and the `goto` should go away.

An example is:

```
size_t frsize;
do {
    while (!sb->free) {
        if (sb->next == NULL) {
            /* Reached end of big block */
            return NULL;
        }
        sb = sb->next;
    }

    /* Remaining space in small block */
    frsize = sb->end - (((void*)sb) + sizeof(memblock));

    /* If there isn't enough space to fit a new small block
     * find another block that will fit one */
} while (frsize >= size + sizeof(memblock));
```

It's not strictly equivalent because in the original version you skip a `free` check under certain conditions. I'm not clear on whether this is a problem.

### Pointer math

```
size_t frsize = sb->end - (((void*)sb) + sizeof(memblock));
```

seems a little awkward. Can you not just:

```
size_t frsize = (sb->end - sb - 1)*sizeof(memblock);
```

I'm surprised that the original version - subtracting non-void and void pointers - is even allowed.

### Forever-loops

You mix styles:

```
do { } while (1);

while (1) { }
```

I don't love either. The clearest to me is usually `while (true) { }`, which is possible given that you have `stdbool`.

In the first case it shouldn't actually be a `while` loop;

```
unsigned int ind = 0;
do {
    ind++;
} while (1);
```

I find would be cleaner as

```
for (unsigned int ind = 0;; ind++)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I've replaced the do-while loop with a for loop as per your suggestion, along with trimming the includes and getting rid of printf. As for everything being in the header, for me that's simply a prototyping method. It's easy to separate code once its written, but its faster to just write it in one place and then separate it at the end imho. Also, since the question was looking for any advice for performance optimizations, do you have any comments about that?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see any obvious optimizations. Have you profiled?

Comment: I have! Currently almost all of the performance overhead is from the mmap in bbinit. Would mremap be faster if I just expand/contract my memory region?

Comment: The correct way to spell "forever" in C is `for (;;)`.

Comment: @CodyGray : it's a matter of perosnal preference, the for has been long considered such because it was use in a very popluar C book, the author themselves said there was no difference and it's a matter of personnal preference. See the answer there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186809/endless-loop-in-c-c

Comment: In addition to Reinderen's very excellent input, a doubly-linked list is not _personally_ how I would choose to manage my memory allocations. And the only reason `prev` is there at all, it looks like, is so that you can patch the linked list back together following a deletion? Feh. Use an array as an allocation table, or something. Or maybe one array per `bblk`, fixed-size. The table size will limit the amount of fragmentation any one block can handle, but arguably that's a _feature_ rather than a bug.

Comment: @FeRD - that belongs in a separate answer, perhaps with a little justification.

Comment: @Walfrat That's true: it is a matter of *style*. Therefore, it's a combination of personal preference and also precedent (which dictates familiarity and thus readability). There's a strong precedent for `for (;;)`, even though the various forms are equivalent. I have a strong *personal* preference for `for (;;)`, but that's more because I have a strong personal preference for rewriting *most* loops as `for` loops (which is always possible; `for` and `do`/`while` are just different ways of writing the same thing).

Comment: I do also use for by default and only fallback to while/do while in the case where they're needed. And in fact I might get quite annoyed if I would meet people using while/do..while instead of for (for something else than infinite loop). Because if I see a while, i'm assuming we're doing something else than another simple walking through a collection.

Answer (score 4):

> ... looking for help speeding up some code

**Functional concern**

I see no provisional to insure the allocation meets universal alignment as `malloc()` does.  This is a potential fatal error.  Also research `max_align_t`.

> `7.22.3 Memory management functions`  The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is
> suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement ...

Even super aligning the `size` a bit more, like to a multiple of 16 or 32 can result in less fragmentation, effecting faster matches after `lfree()` for later allocations.

---

Rest is minor stuff.

---

**Avoid mis-alignment**

Certainly a pointer and `size_t` may have the same size and alignment needs, but what if they do not?

Although a `struct *` could be narrower on some unicorn platform, the reverse is more likely: the pointer wider and performs better aligned well.

```
typedef bblock* bb;
struct bblk {
    size_t ind;
    bb next;
    size_t occ;
    char mem[PAGESIZE - (sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(bb) + sizeof(size_t))];
} __attribute__((packed));
```

In general, put the widest members first and like with like.

```
typedef bblock* bb;
struct bblk {
    bb next; // First
    size_t ind;
    size_t occ;
    char mem[PAGESIZE - (sizeof(bb) + sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(size_t))];
} __attribute__((packed));
```

In general this applies to `struct smmblk` too, but only benefits in rare implementations where `struct *` narrower than `void *`.

```
struct smmblk {
    void* end; // void * certainly widest object point when objects pointer sizes differ.
    mb prev;
    mb next;
    bb bblk;
    bool free;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

**Set aside `packed`**

It is not portable and tends to make data that is memory space efficient at the cost of speed.

**`free(NULL)` is OK yet not `lfree(NULL)`**

Consider adding an internal `NULL` test to allow users that same latitude as `free()`.

---

**Hiding pointer types**

`typedef bblock* bb;` and later use of `bb` hides that fact `bb` is a pointer and makes deciphering the code and ideas for improvements more challenging.

**Avoid UB**

`void *` addition is UB (or IDB) and distracts from performance analysis.  Consider `unsigned char *` or `char *`.

```
// ((void*)sb) + sizeof(memblock)
((unsigned char*) sb) + sizeof memblock

void* a
// mb sb = a - sizeof(memblock);
// mb sb = (mb) ((unsigned char *)a - sizeof(memblock));
```

Comment: I was planning to implement the alignment for allocation at a later point - agree it is important feature. I've also implemented the check for free(NULL). The hidden pointer types are only until I feel that this code is in a decent enough state to separate into a .c/.h file and be 'done' ish. As for the ```packed```, I was going to get rid of it, but when I did, I profiled again and lost some performance. Ideas? I find that very confusing.

Comment: @LevKnoblock The performance of allocation is highly dependent on the nature of allocations and free scenarios.  A string heavy application vs. a heavy link list versus multi-precision math math can give a inconsistent performance ranking between implementations.  "lost some performance" sounds too minor.   Look to avoiding worst case scenarios (reduce [big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)) and strive for general performance.